# Fetching profile picture info

Tags: python, django, sqlite

While I am trying put login with google in my Django web framework, the username in Gmail fetched using:

```
<a>Hello {{ user.get_full_name|default:user.username }}!</a>
```

In my `home.html file.

My question is to how can I get the profile picture of my Gmail account in the same HTML?

Comment: did you mean is like gravatar image?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get